# How to get DigitalOcean to run script on boot via REST API?

Tags: digital-ocean

I `POST` the following data to https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets

```
{
    "name":"1470293222",
    "image":"ubuntu-16-04-x64",
    "size":"512mb",
    "user_data":"#!/bin/bash\ncurl http://www.myserver.com",
    "region":"nyc1"
}
```

This should create a new droplet and run the script in user_data, but not matter what I do, I can't seem to get the script to run.

Strangely if I launch a Droplet from the DigitalOcean console, which appears NOT to use the REST API, then the `userdata` script appears to work OK

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make a DigitalOcean boot script work?

Comment: the docu provides good examples. maybe your "\n" does not work: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/provide-user-data/

Answer (score 0):

What response are you receiving when you send that request? Based on the DigitalOcean [API documentation for creating a droplet](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/create_droplet), it appears that your `size` field is incorrect. Instead of using `512mb`, try something like `s-1vcpu-1gb`.